# Incorrect Syntax Near '('

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

can anybody tell me why the following code produces the error:

```
cQueryIS = "UPDATE Additional (StaffEUPN, Class, Additional1, Additional2, Additional3, Additional4,AdditionalLarge1, AdditionalLarge2, AdditionalLarge3, AdditionalLarge4)  "

cQueryIS &= "VALUES (@cSTEupn, @cClass, @cAdditional1, @cAdditional2, @cAdditional3, @cAdditional4, @cAdditionalLarge1, @cAdditionalLarge2, @cAdditionalLarge3, @cAdditionalLarge4) "

cQueryIS &= "WHERE StaffEUPN = '" & cStaffEUPN & "' AND Class = '" & cClass & "'"
```

However this code works:

```
cQueryIS = "UPDATE Additional SET StaffEUPN=@cSTEupn, Class=@cClass, 
Additional1=@cAdditional1, Additional2=@cAdditional2, Additional3=@cAdditional3,
Additional4=@cAdditional4, AdditionalLarge1=@cAdditionalLarge1, 
AdditionalLarge2=@cAdditionalLarge2, AdditionalLarge3=@cAdditionalLarge3, 
AdditionalLarge4=@cAdditionalLarge4  "

cQueryIS &= "WHERE StaffEUPN = '" & cStaffEUPN & "' AND Class = '" 
& cClass & "'"
```

I am a bit confused as the way I did it first works fine on an `INSERT` command and only causes the error on an `UPDATE`.

Here is the rest of the code:

```
        Using dbConnectionSQL As New SqlConnection(dbConnectionString)
            Using comm As New SqlCommand()
                With comm
                    .Connection = dbConnectionSQL
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    .CommandText = cQueryIS
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@cSTEupn", cStaffEUPN)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@cClass", cClass)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@cAdditional1", ProvisionAdditional(1))
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@cAdditional2", ProvisionAdditional(2))
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@cAdditional3", ProvisionAdditional(3))
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@cAdditional4", ProvisionAdditional(4))
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@cAdditionalLarge1", ProvisionAdditional(5))
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@cAdditionalLarge2", ProvisionAdditional(6))
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@cAdditionalLarge3", ProvisionAdditional(7))
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@cAdditionalLarge4", ProvisionAdditional(8))
                End With
                Try
                    dbConnectionSQL.Open()
                    comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Catch ex As SqlException
                    WriteToLogFile("Update Additional", ex.Message.ToString())
                    MsgBox("Update Additional - " & ex.Message.ToString())
                    Exit Sub
                End Try
            End Using
        End Using
```

Comment: Because you mix `insert` and `update` syntax.

Comment: Do you mean the VALUES way can only be used for an INSERT command?

Comment: Update commands must use `SET <field> = <expression>, ...`, whereas inserts can use the VALUES syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in your first example, you're using `INSERT` syntax on the `UPDATE` command. In the second sample, you're using correct `UPDATE` syntax.

The syntax for `INSERT` and `UPDATE` are different. You should read the docs, but generally:

```
INSERT INTO <Table> (Field1, ..., FieldN) VALUES (Value1, ..., ValueN)
vs.
UPDATE <Table> SET Field1 = Value1, ..., FieldN = ValueN WHERE <Condition>
```

There are some more ways you can use this, but basically that's it.

Comment: Thats great thanks, I am new to VB.NET and this is my first Programme using SQL Server. Coming from VB6 and Access !

Comment: It's not a VB.NET problem, however, it's a misunderstanding of SQL. Also: Thumbs up for using parameterized queries from the start!

Comment: Thanks for the vote of confidance :-) I must say I am getting use to vb.net however the lack of Control Arrays make life a little harder than it should be !